# TypeOrm in NestJS: Single Table Inheritance Repository not returning properties of most specific type

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

Currently I'm having the following Structure:

I have an `abstract class AocMessage` with properties such as `received`, `from` and `to`.
In addition I have class `FreetextMessage` that extends the `abstract class AocMessage` with a property like `message`.

Later on I will have multiple classes that extend this abstract class and I want to store them all within one table.

I did so using the following code:

```js
@Entity()
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: 'varchar', name: 'type' } })
export abstract class AocMessage {
    ...
}
```

and

```js
@ChildEntity()
export class FreetextMessage extends AocMessage {
    ...
}
```

In my service which will handle the DB queries I have the following code:

```js
class AocService {
    constructor(
        ...
        @InjectRepository(AocMessage)
        private readonly messageRepository: Repository<AocMessage>,
        ...
    ) {
        ...
    }

    async fetchMessages() {
        ...
        const messages = await this.messageRepository.find({ ... });
        ...
    }
}
```

But when loggin the messages returned by the `find()`-method they always do only have the properties of the abstract class AocMessage instead of the inserted FreetextMessage. Why is that?